# npm Error! ENOENT: no such file or directory .dezalgo.DELETE'

Tags: javascript, node.js, laravel, npm

Whenever I try to do anything with my NPM I keep on getting this error.

I try to install `npm install -g --save vue-draggable`

I have uninstalled node and npm and re installed and constantly having this issue.

npm ERR! path /Users/victor/Desktop/myprog/node_modules/jquery/node_modules/npm/node_modules/dezalgo

NPM Verson: 5.6.0

Node: v8.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone having this problem, its because NPM is version 5.6.0

Downgrade to:

```
Sudo npm install -g npm@4.6.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the accepted solution will solve the issue...

Somehow a dependancy representation in `package-lock.json` is wrongly described.

Removing the file `package-lock.json` and `npm install` **could** solve the issue.

I recommend that you use the latest version of npm : `npm install npm@lastest`.